# Importing pandas dataframe as layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, pandas

I'm working on a dataset that is readily available as a `pandas` dataframe object. Now, I would like to import this data as a layer in QGIS. I didn't find any helpful library or code to do so. So, I resorted to converting the dataframe to a `csv` file and then importing this as a layer using PyQGIS api.

Is there any way I can import the dataframe directly, without having to write it to a shapefile or a `csv` file?

Comment: Do you have geometries in the dataframe or is it only a table?

Comment: It is only a table.

Comment: Can you show us what your dataframe looks like? You can probably use memory layer. Just convert each line of your dataframe to feature.

Comment: If you use pandas inside QGIS you can write to a QGSVectorLayer stored in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe is in-memory object that lives inside your Jupyter Notebook (or other development tool) and QGIS reads from file.
There is no simple way to move objects between different processes.